# Python 3.x Running issue, ALL IDEA cannot read the library of Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sorry if this is quite simple question, but I'VE searched all over internet and couldn't find the solution. When i run this code in VS or by python in cmd it runnig fine, but like Atom, Sublime, VisualStudioCode it shows me this. I tried everything to solve this, but nothing worked out. Even wrote in tope of code this

```py
 #!/usr/bin/python

 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

But didn't work!

MY CODE AND OUTPUT BELOW:

```py
from colorama import init

from colorama import Fore, Back, Style

init()

print(Back.BLACK)

print(Fore.GREEN)

what=input("Что будем делать, детка? -, +, *, /, **, %: ")

print(Back.BLACK)

print(Fore.CYAN)

a=float(input('Детка, введи первое число: '))

b=float(input('Детка, введи второе число, если ты ее еще помнишь: '))

d=float(input('Детка, введи третье число, хорошенько подумай!: '))

print(Back.BLACK)

print(Fore.RED)

if what=="+":

    c=a+b

    print(str(c))

elif what=="-":

    c=a-b

    print(str(c))

elif what=="*":

    c=a*b

    print(str(c))

elif what=="/":

    c=a/b

    print(str(c))

elif what=="*+":

    c=a*(b+d)

    print(str(c))

else:

    print('Детка, ты хоть выспалась?!')
```

THE OUTPUT:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\Projects\PythonProjects\PythonTestsFromHAUDIHOU\test2.py", line 9, in <module>

    what=input("\u0427\u0442\u043e \u0431\u0443\u0434\u0435\u043c \u0434\u0435\u043b\u0430\u0442
\u044c, \u0434\u0435\u0442\u043a\u0430? -, +, *, /, **, %: ")

  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 41, in write
    self.__convertor.write(text)

  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 162, in write
    self.write_and_convert(text)

  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 190, in write_and_convert

    self.write_plain_text(text, cursor, len(text))

  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 195, in write_plain_text
    self.wrapped.write(text[start:end])

  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: character maps to <undefined>

[Finished in 0.163s]
```

Comment: *Offtopic: That's how python developers have sex*.

Comment: lol, but i'm serious. Is there any way to run the code in Atom, Sublime, VisualStudioCode?

Comment: Check file encoding.

Comment: How can I check it? You mean about                                                                     #!/usr/bin/python

 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-  ?

Comment: No, I mean file encoding. Simplest way is to open file in notepad and choose "Save As". In popup window you will see "Encoding" combobox.

Comment: UTF-8. Saved as xxx.py but still the same